# Internal server error when user's IP changes (probably has something to do with PHP session file locking)

Tags: php, session, timeout, internal-server-error

I have a website written in PHP. One of the users is in a building where they have two internet connections with two ISP's, but one network. So, any computer on the network may connect through either web connection, and it appears that the switch sometimes happens mid-request. Sometimes this leads to internal server errors on my script. Sadly, the logs on my shared host don't seem to have a lot of detail.

So, here's my guess. My script uses sessions. The user sends a request with internet connection 1 and this locks the session file. As that request is processing, internet connection 1 is shut off and internet connection 2 is turned on. Apache/PHP keeps trying to send the response back to internet connection 1 (which no longer exists). User tries to reload page via internet connection 2. PHP waits for the initial script to exit and unlock the session file, but it never does, so it eventually dies with an internal server error.

So, how might I get around this? Is there a way to force un-lock a session file if too much time has passed since it was last locked? (No script has ever taken more than 3 seconds to execute, so if the lock is more than, say, 15 seconds old, that means that the old script is waiting around to serve a file to the wrong IP address and could be killed.) Thanks!

Comment: What your apache error log says?

Comment: this an issue with their network connection, and nothing to do with your site? surely they have the same issues connecting to other sites?

Comment: I don't think it's sessions.  It just uses a browser cookie to determine which session file to open.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. So, the issue, as far as I can tell, was that the server did not unlock the session file if a request was started but then failed due to the funky internet connection. So, the user sends a request, session_start() is called and the session file is locked, the server starts sending a response to the client, but the client half-disappears. Client sends a new request via the new IP address, session_start() is called, but that has to wait for the session file to be unlocked, so that just waits and waits and eventually times out. However, I solved this for my site. So, here's the way my site works:
 1. Server gets request.
 2. Server does processing of request and stores information for user in various variables rather than an echo-as-you-go method.
 3. Then I include template.php, and my various saved variables are displayed in the correct location.
So, my code flow does all processing first, and then all user-echoing after the processing is done. So, at the beginning of the template.php file, I now included a "session_write_close();". That releases the session file manually before the response is sent to the user, instead of waiting until the script ends. So, if the user disappears during the transfer, the session file is unlocked and the user can send a new request and it won't bump into a locked session file.

Since I put in that fix, I haven't heard any more complaints. (As a side note, the user does have issues with other websites, but I want my site to react in the best manner possible to a sub-par internet connection.)